# What's the difference between class and category?

Tags: differences, synonyms, word-usage

[George Firican said the ER (entity relationship) is different for classification and categorization.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1_5BMeO-uc)

The ERs according to him

For classification

- members : classes
- 1:n (one to many)
- A futon can be in the bed xor couch class.

For categorization

- members : categories
- m:n (many to many)
- A futon can be in the bed and/or couch category.

That would mean classes are mutually exclusive, and categories aren't.

There are many synonyms for this where I don't know the difference (set, class, group, category, type, kind, branch, bracket, division, etc.).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates specifically to the usage of the terms in computing science — specifically relational databases — rather than their general English meaning. Likewise the other terms may be used to differentiate specific data structures etc. The word chosen may or may not reflect its general meaning, but this is irrelevant once it has been accepted. The question should be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello, David. I'm afraid that few native speakers will have heard of, never mind use, the stipulative definitions Firican uses. If you look in recognised dictionaries, I think you'll agree that few if any highlight a fundamental distinction between 'class' and 'category'. For instance, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class) lists many senses and subsenses of 'class', some of which doubtless partly conflict even with each other. // If you're using Firican as a mentor, learn and stick with his terminology while in class. But in the real world, be flexible.